# Setting spark Parameters for Performance Tuning, outOfMemoryError Gc and GC limit exceeded

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

**I have 5 modes each having 8 cpu cores and 30GB memory.I have 5GB of dataset1 and 65GB of dataset2 so i need to Join them and save to s3 file system and i set following parameters :**

```
--num-executors 4 --spark.driver.memory 8g --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 27g  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=824m
```

But, I searched everywhere and tried different parameters , still i am getting out of memory error. Gc overhead limit exceeded.

Also used this in Java Code :

```
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
conf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", AvgRegistrator.class.getName());
conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "5g");
conf.set("spark.broadcast.compress", "true");
conf.set("spark.shuffle.compress", "true");
```

No any solutions in stackoverflow are working for me . so can anyone give me a better solution to get rid of this problem.

```
Spark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

and some time i am getting this :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to increase the level of paralellism (i.e. split your partitions into smaller ones).

If you have only a few partitons in the underlying storage, then you have to manually repartition the data before the join (e.g. by calling `repartition()` on your Datasets or RDDs). In addition, setting the `spark.default.parallelism` property can help if you are using RDDs. If you are using Datasets, consider the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` parameter, which defines the number of partitions after each shuffle operation.

Comment: Already tried with different partitions. not working , :( How many partitions should i make for my above configurations ? . I have 200 partitions of total 8GB in first dataset , and  99 partitions of total 65 GB of data in another dataset.

Comment: That  sounds line enough. Can you update the question with the code and Spark version that you use?

Comment: Also, you are setting the `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` parameter to a value that is smaller than the default one (equals to executorMemory * 0.10).

Comment: I am submiting on standalone mode .